# What's cons for using too many responsive media screen query

Tags: html, css

I want my desktop to mobile site change flawlessly. So my design for the site it has to be good for any screen resolution size. This causing me using a lot of media query screen. Let say for max 990px, max 800px, max 600px etc. Closer to smaller size, it get a lot of media screen. If possible, I'm using percent, but if not possible, I'll use lots of media screen query. Maybe in total on a single page there's 20 or more media query in total (main css style and plugins)

Is there any set back to this? Any cons? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Many times readability/maintainability are more difficult the more sizes you add. From what I've seen, around 3 media query sizes tends to be sufficient. Sass `includes` can make this easier also.

Comment: Can you elaborate this "readability/maintainability are more difficult the more sizes you add"? Is this "readability" by the browser or by human visitor? If by human visitor, the sole reason I use lots of media queries is to make it good at any resolution because nowdays a lot of mobile devices have non regular screen wide, I mean now not just 240px, 320px, 360px, 480px etc http://mydevice.io/devices/

Comment: unnecessary added complexity & added style file size

Comment: Yeah, readability and maintainability on your (the developer) side. Imagine you've made a website and some of the specifications change (it happens often). Well now instead of one or two small changes, you have to change for every device size. And testing becomes a nightmare. Generally its bad practice to target specific devices with CSS, but its easier and more maintainable to make a design that flows between screen resolutions. Future you will thank you.

Comment: trix & cameron : I see, totally agree, it's hard to have such complex media queries. I will keep in mind to keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 2):

In short

- ***maintainability***

Long document and complex syntax reduces readability and increase pain and effort to modify CSS rules in the future.

- ***performance***

Too many media queries add length, longer CSS file would cause user spend more time downloading them into the browser and render the correct view.

---

For the sake of 'you in the future', design and structure the layout cross varied devices carefully. Some tools like ["include-media"](http://include-media.com/) and ["sass-mq"](https://github.com/sass-mq/sass-mq) will surely enhance the readability and save work time as well.

Comment: Definitely gonna consider those 2 for future projects. Lots to learn here. Thanks.